# How to solve error 7347 in linked server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have two database, MySQL and SQL Server

I have created linked server between these database and I didn't have any problem but when I wanted transfer data from MySQL to SQL Server, I faced with this problem:

> OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'TWITTER' returned data that does not match expected data length for column '[MSDASQL].t_u_description'. The (maximum) expected data length is 30, while the returned data length is 55.

In two databases, my table and column and data type is same, but I don't know, how to solve this problem?

My data in this column(t_u_description) is non-english

Comment: What are datatypes of this columns?

Comment: And the character coding used? What character set do you use as connection character set when you configured the connection to MySQL? This seems to me a multi byte character set interpreted as a single byte character set issue. The 30 is the maximum length in characters, but if the data is interpreted by byte, then the length is longer.

Comment: my datatype is varchar(30)

Comment: And the character coding used? where do you say? in odbc?

Comment: thanks from everyone that try to help me, my problem solved, i added "college utf8_persian_ci" from every column that had non-english when i run select operation